# The directory '/home/deploy/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user

Tags: server, nginx

[image]

I'm trying to download ngxtop to monitor nginx on 16.04 LTS

```
deploy@server:~$ sudo pip install ngxtop
[sudo] password for deploy:
The directory '/home/deploy/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/deploy/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting ngxtop
  Downloading ngxtop-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from ngxtop)
  Downloading pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |################################| 61kB 4.6MB/s
Collecting docopt (from ngxtop)
  Downloading docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code -9 in /tmp/pip-build-qdsM8k/docopt/
Killed
```

How can I get this working ?

Edit:

```
deploy@server:~$ sudo -H pip install ngxtop
[sudo] password for deploy:
Collecting ngxtop
  Downloading ngxtop-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from ngxtop)
  Downloading pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |################################| 61kB 8.0MB/s
Collecting docopt (from ngxtop)
  Downloading docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
Collecting tabulate (from ngxtop)
  Downloading tabulate-0.7.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: docopt
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for docopt ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-umz2So/docopt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpPmBPnfpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for docopt
  Running setup.py clean for docopt
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-umz2So/docopt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for docopt
Failed to build docopt
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, docopt, tabulate, ngxtop
  Running setup.py install for docopt ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-umz2So/docopt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hUhxBo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-umz2So/docopt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hUhxBo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code -9 in /tmp/pip-build-umz2So/docopt/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.


deploy@server:~$ pip install --upgrade pip --user
Collecting pip
Killed
deploy@server:~$
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's going to work give it a try if it worked I'll sent it as an answer: first update the pip: `pip install --upgrade pip --user` then upgrade setuptools: `pip install --upgrade setuptools --user` then try to install your package again: `pip install ngxtop --user`

Comment: Try it this way: `sudo -H pip install ngxtop`

Comment: Hi guys, I tried both methods. The results are in the edit above:

Comment: The problem was that the swap space was turned off on my VPS!! I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04 and found that "free -h" returned 0. I asked the vps to turn on the vswap and the package installed.